# $\exists x\forall y ((x + y \in X) \wedge (x - y)\in Z)$

Tags: set-theory

U = $\begin{Bmatrix}
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
\end{Bmatrix}$

X = $\begin{Bmatrix}
0,1,2,3,4
\end{Bmatrix}$

Z = $\begin{Bmatrix}
1,3,5,7,9
\end{Bmatrix}$

Is this true? $\exists x\forall y ((x + y \in X) \wedge   (x - y)\in Z)$

**My solution:**

(x+y) =X (x-y) = Z

**x = 2 and y = 1**

2+1 = 3  2-1 =1

**x = 2 and y = 2**

2+2 = 4 2-2 = 0

trying different x for y = 2

**x = 1 and y = 2**

1+2 = 3 1-2 = -2

Am I doing this right? The statement seems false to me.

Comment: For $x=0$ there is no $y$ such that $x-y\in Z$.

Comment: I think x could be anything 0-9, but for y = 0 x could be 1 then we get 1-0  = 0 (Z)

Comment: And also 1+0 = 1 (X)

Comment: The proposition in your title is different from the proposition in the text of your question.  Both are false, but which do you intend?

Comment: Ok sorry thanks, that one in the text, yes i thought it was false thanks :)

Comment: What is the set $U$ for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that such $x$ exists, since it must work for every $y$ (in $U$ I suppose), it must work for $y=0$. So $x\in X$ and $x\in Z$. So it must be 1 or 3 but neither 1 nor 3 fits the property.